# using MAx and group by in DB2

Tags: db2

I 'am Executing the Query below in DB2

```
select SOURCE1 , PLANT1,  max(BEGIN_TIMESTAMP) as dat , END_TIMESTAMP,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(2,CAST((END_TIMESTAMP - BEGIN_TIMESTAMP) AS CHAR(22))) 
from tab1
group by dat
```

however i am getting this error :

2:01:01  [SELECT - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: -206, SQL State: 42703]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=DAT, DRIVER=3.50.152
... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]

Any idea Please

Comment: Side note: (In part due to the relative interval returned by the timestamp subtraction,) `TIMESTAMPDIFF` returns an **estimate**.  In particular, the value will be off once you have a months (at least 1 day) or years (5 or 6 days).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include all non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY`.  It is unclear exactly what you want, but this should at least parse and run:

```
select SOURCE1, PLANT1,  max(BEGIN_TIMESTAMP) as dat , END_TIMESTAMP,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(2, CAST((END_TIMESTAMP - BEGIN_TIMESTAMP) AS CHAR(22))) 
from tab1
group by SOURCE1, PLANT1, END_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: It’s run with you suggestion thanks.
However it does not turn the correct results